# How to get rid of the strip behind a button from xml in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, button

When i try to import a button from an xml layout file into my View, I get a white strip running vertically along the button when I run the app. The button is found in my layout xml file which I used to integrate with the View. A screenshot can be shown here:(Button is at bottom left of the screen) http://i844.photobucket.com/albums/ab9/lewweihao93/ScreenHunter_01%20Jul.%2026%2018.20_zpsa1idaeao.jpg

The following is the xml code of my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="25dp"
        android:layout_height="25dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:text="FIRE"
        android:id="@+id/b" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The following is the relevant part of my main code:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        layout = (LinearLayout) View.inflate(this, R.layout.mbb, null);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        surfaceview=new mbbs(this);
        surfaceview.setOnTouchListener(this);
        layout.addView(surfaceview);
        b=(Button)findViewById(R.id.b);
        shot=new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        id=shot.load(this, R.raw.shots,1);
        bomb=new SoundPool(5, AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC,0);
        id2=bomb.load(this, R.raw.bomb, 1);
        Bundle basket2=getIntent().getExtras();
        difficulty=basket2.getString("key");
        if (difficulty.equals("e"))
            {pace=2;}
        else if (difficulty.equals("m"))
        {pace=5;}
        else if (difficulty.equals("h"))
        {pace=10;}


        bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ball);
        plusv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.plusv);
        minusv = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.minusv);
        launch = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.launch);
        target = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.target);
        cannon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.cannon);
        bg = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.bg);

        setContentView(layout);
        tx=1000;tx2=1000;tx3=1000;tx4=1000;tx5=1000;
        bx=0;
```

How do I get rid of the vertical strip along the button?Is this a good way to integrate a layout into a View?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of it?

Comment: I've added a link to the screenshot

Comment: Are you sure that that's the right image? I can't find the mentioned button anywhere...

Comment: It's at the bottom left of the screen

Comment: I was having trouble seeing that button as well. Just look at the left border - there is a gray stripe accross height and on the bottom of that is mention button. Man, You should point it out more with arrows or smoething.